# What is the reason for the error message `Can't locate object method "get_ok"` when using WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I couldn't really figure out how to use [WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aTreeBuilder). Basically I get a HTML page using [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize). There is a `//div[@class='cars']` whose text I want to extract.

I tried:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get('the url');
WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply($mech);
$mech->get_ok('//div[@class="cars"]');
print $mech->look_down(_tag => 'p')->as_trimmed_text . "\n";
```

It says:

```
Can't locate object method "get_ok" via package "Class::MOP::Class::__ANON__::SERIAL::2" at orpi_crawler.pl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_ok` is from `Test::WWW::Mechanize` which you neglected to load. Read the synopsis of `WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder` carefully.